# add js file to catalog page magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, catalog, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I am using Magento 2.2.1. I want to add a js file to change one special span tag content with CSS class "price" on the catalog page. I was using document.getelementnByClass.. for my js development. and my question is how to accept that in my Magento 2 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requireJs in your phtml File and use jquery for that

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
    ], function ($) {
       //here write your code :) 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the best way.it works good

Answer (score 0):

You can add JS files for the catalog page by layout method:

Add below code in **catalog_product_view.xml** file:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Catalog::catalog_custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then create **catalog_custom.js** file inside Catalog module at path **view/frontend/web/js/catalog_custom.js**

```
require([
   'jquery'
], function ($) {
     // your custom code
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering. one question arises. how can I add the js file to the module catalog and not change the vendor folder? I have a custom theme and I know working with it and as the same custom module.does it enough to add js file to {Theme_Dir}/Magento_Catalog/web/js ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add js file as same path {Theme_Dir}/Magento_Catalog/web/js

Comment: If this answer is useful for you then feel free to accept the answer.